# XNA - Offscreen Vertices Optimization

Tags: xna-4.0

Okay, I have a set of vertices that is around 10,000,000 (it's a long story, but it seems that it is needed), however only a few thousand of those will be onscreen at a time. It's currently setup as one vertex buffer (and it's one shape anyway) so the normal view frustum culling solution would not seem to be applicable here.

Is there any way of making it only drawing those few thousand verticies needed onscreen at one time?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be organizing the model's triangles (not vertices) into a spatial hierarchy system like an octree. Then test the octree against the view frustum.

The XNA sample library has the ['ship game sample'](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/starterkit/shipgame) that does this for collision testing of player's bounding box to the walls of the map(which are organized into the octree). But it wouldn't be much harder to test it against a view frustum as a bounding box.

Comment: The wikipedia article on space partitioning: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning